# Pandas - String values encoding

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone please suggest what is the best way to encode string features wherein I have > 500 unique features. Does this fall under categorical Data?
I need to basically normalize data with string features having huge number of unique features and adjacent features are co-realted. ( eg. col1 and col2 have a particular combination for one class in classification Problem. Similarly col3 and col4 again have some fixed pattern for each class)
How do I encode my data in this scenario before making it ready for ML algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to encode categorical features. The best way really depends on your dataset and which ML algorithm you are going to use, so you could try different encoding schemes and pick the one that has the best results.

I've worked with categorical features with hundreds of unique values (e.g. Product Brands) and with tree-based algorithms and a **label-encoder** worked well with the algorithm.

For example you could use the scikit-learn [label encoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html):

```
>>> le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
>>> le.fit(["paris", "paris", "tokyo", "amsterdam"])
LabelEncoder()
>>> list(le.classes_)
['amsterdam', 'paris', 'tokyo']
>>> le.transform(["tokyo", "tokyo", "paris"]) 
array([2, 2, 1]...)
>>> list(le.inverse_transform([2, 2, 1]))
['tokyo', 'tokyo', 'paris']
```

You can do that in pandas as well, for example, if you have a column with the string categories you want to encode you could try this:

```
df["categorical_feature"] = df["categorical_feature"].astype('category')
df["categorical_feature_enc"] = df["categorical_feature"].cat.codes
```

Another useful encoding you could try is the one-hot encoding. However, since you have a lot of categories to encode that would result in an addition of n columns to your dataset per categorical feature (n = number of categories). Check the pandas [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) to see an example.